# Using <Grow> on <Tab>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui I'm attempting to iterate an array and render a item value as a tab. I'd like to have the tabs grow on load as per this example https://material-ui.com/utils/transitions/#grow.

I'm able to effectively do the iteration and show the tabs as follows;

```
 <Tabs fullWidth value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} scrollable>
 {this.props.myArray.map((p, i) =>
     <Tab value={p.value} label={`${p.value}`}/>)}
 </Tabs>
```

The logical approach would be;

```
<Tabs fullWidth value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} scrollable>
{this.props.myArray.map((p, i) =>
    <Grow in={true} timeout={500}
        <Tab value={p.value} label={`${p.value}`}/>
    </Grow>)}
</Tabs>
```

But this does not work, "p" becomes inaccessible and it does not apply the Grow effect.

Is my best option to use the Tab source and create my own component that implements a transition as outlined here https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition?
I'm happy to do this, but would obviously prefer the above method if there is a simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Judging by the shown code, there is no reason why would p become inaccessible. Do you have some error in console?

Comment: Yes it's showing the tab item index rather than the value when I output p.value.
I could work around this, if the grow transition would work.